# Proof that A is diagonalizable if for all eigenvalues $\lambda$, Im$(\lambda I-A)$=Im$(\lambda I-A)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

A is matrix.
i need to prove that: for all eigenvalues $\lambda$,  Im$(\lambda I-A)$=Im$(\lambda I-A)^2$ then A is diagonalizable.
i have not idea how to start.

---

### EDIT:  my solution

IM$(A-\lambda I)=$IM$(A-\lambda I)^2$ $\Rightarrow$ NUL$(A-\lambda I)=$NUL$(A-\lambda I)^s$ for all $s$ then $K_{\lambda}=\lbrace v : (A-\lambda I)^p v=0$ for some $p>0\rbrace =$ $\bigcup\limits_{s}$ NUL$(A-\lambda I)^s=$ E $_\lambda$

since $\mathbb{C}^n=\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda}$K$_{\lambda}=\bigoplus\limits_{\lambda}$E$_{\lambda}$ therefore therefore there exists a basis of eigenvectors and thus, A is diagonalizable

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you are working over an algebraically closed field, then you might want to take a look at the Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: @Nico According to the comment, it should show that the minimal polynomial $(x-\lambda_1) ^ {a_1} (x-\lambda_2) ^ {a_2} \cdots (x-\lambda_k) ^ {a_k}$ then $a_i = 1$ for all i? because $A=P^{-1}JP$

Comment: If you take, e.g., matrix $3 I$, then the characteristic polynomial is $(x-3)^3$, so that is not true. You should rather look at how large can the Jordan cells be in the Jordan Normal Form. In particular, if you take $A$ to be one Jordan cell with the one eigenvalue $\lambda$ (that is, $\lambda$'s on the diagonal, $1$'s one place above the diagonal, and $0$'s everywhere else), what can you tell about $\mathrm{Im}(\lambda I -A)$ and $\mathrm{Im}((\lambda I - A)^2)$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you said minimal polynomial. Disregard the first sentence of my comment.

Comment: the exercise OP should do first is, working on the coordinate vector space $V=\mathbb F^n$ then $\text{rank}\big(B^2\big)= \text{rank}\big(B\big)\implies V = \text{image }B \oplus \ker B$, then deduce the eigenvalue zero is *semi-simple*.  The result follows e.g. when $\mathbb F$ is algebracailly closed and then by translation, i.e. setting $B:=\lambda_k -I$, implies all $\lambda_k$ are *semi-simple*.  Jordan forms are overkill here.  The essence of this is learning to exploit the equality conditions of $\text{rank}\big(XY\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(X\big)$. I'd like to see an attempt by OP.

Comment: @Lenin Angarita First observe that your condition is independent of the basis. If it holds in one basis, the it holds in any other. If the field is algebraically closed, then there is a basis such that the matrix is in JNF. It consists of Jordan blocks. The eigenvalues are on the diagonal and there are some 1s on the offdiagonal. Now you can see that your condition holds if and only if there are no 1s on the off diagonal, i.e. iff the JNF is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Can you check my edit please ?